# What does <c-r>= means in Vim

Tags: vim

I came across a number of this syntax usages which I don't understand:

The first is in :help mapping:

```
:map <F2> a<C-R>=strftime("%c")<CR><Esc>
```

This sequence really does insert the value of strftime into buffer though I don't understand how. Changing  onto something different breaks it.

Another one is at wiki [page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Improve_completion_popup_menu) which describes how to make omnicompletion popup menu work well:

```
inoremap <silent> <Esc> <C-r>=pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "\<Esc>"<CR>
```

The same thing here.

Can anybody explain how this "`<C-r>=`" thing works?...

Comment: <C-R> overall is just just used to insert something from a buffer/register. Registers are accessed through ```"```, and <C-R> gives you a way to use any of the registers available in vim, you can look at them with ":h <C-R>"

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`<C-r>=`, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> is used to insert the result of an expression at the cursor.

I use it a lot when editing CSS to insert values:

```
width: <C-r>=147-33<CR>px;
width: 114px;
```

***EDIT***

`<C-r>`, without `=`, allows you to insert the content of any register at the cursor while staying in *insert* mode: `<C-r>+`, for example, inserts the content of my system clipboard.  see `:help i_ctrl_r`.

`=` is the "expression register". See `:help "=`.

***ENDEDIT***

Comment: Thank you, romainl, my primarily confusion was with C-r meaning "redo" in normal mode and now I understand the thing!

Comment: to get help on c-r you want `:help c_ctrl-r` (ie second underscore should be hyphen)

Answer (score 40):

`<C-r>` is like doing CTRL+R on the keyboard. `<CR>` is like hitting enter. You can find the full list by doing `:help key-notation`.

Comment: I know this is a very beginner question but, when you do :help key-notation it takes you to the documentation. Then if I press Q it takes me to Ex mode. If I press visual it returns me to normal mode but it takes me back at looking at the documentation. I just want to go back to coding my original python file, how do I go back to it? Thanks so much btw for ur original post! :D

Comment: I guess my question is how do I get back to my original file and get out of the documentation?

Comment: Oh, I discovered how to do it by accident! To get out of the documentation just press : then q. i.e. since it is normal mode just doing :q will exit the documentation and not the actual file. :)

Comment: when help open , it split the window, to move from window to window you can use : <C-w>w. This toogle between the last two windows visited. You can split again and again.....every command to play around with windows starts with <C-w>...

Comment: @Pinocchio If the docs open in split mode, you just close the current windows by `:close`. If it's in fullscreen, do `:b#` to toggle to the previous buffer.